# How to split wordpress meta value data

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I want to get IP address using below meta value. How can i do it ?

"a:19:{s:13:"serial_number";i:51;s:9:"remote_ip";s:15:"123.231.126.147";s:10:"user_agent";s:114:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36";s:3:"url";s:46:"#";s:4:"date";s:14:"March 28, 2020";s:4:"time";s:7:"5:17 am";s:7:"post_id";s:0:"";s:9:"post_name";s:0:"";s:10:"post_title";s:0:"";s:8:"post_url";s:0:"";s:11:"post_author";s:0:"";s:17:"post_author_email";s:0:"";s:10:"site_title";s:8:"nodelete";s:16:"site_description";s:27:"Just another WordPress site";s:8:"site_url";s:33:"#";s:16:"site_admin_email";s:16:"buddika@abc.com";s:10:"user_login";s:0:"";s:10:"user_email";s:0:"";s:17:"user_display_name";s:0:"";}"

Comment: You should probably provide the key if you want a complete or semi-complete answer, and it wouldn't hurt to explain both where and how you extracted the above (directly from the database?) and also where and how (programmatically) you expect to use the IP address.

Comment: Looks like a serialize, use PHP's [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `json_decode()` and use it as an object.

```
$object = json_decode($result);
echo $object->remote_ip;
```